# Using PHP to delete comments from the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

My site is an admin login site, therefore users cannot register. However they can post comments to the site. I have delete buttons on the comments but didn't realise that anybody can then delete anybodies comments. How can I change this so when the admin is logged in they are able to delete inappropriate comments (if any) and get rid of the delete button from the general public.

This is my Comment.php code with the delete button function in there:

```
   <?php 

   session_start();
   require_once 'templates/open.php';
   require_once 'connect.php';
   require_once 'functions/cleanstring.php';
   require_once 'functions/encrypt.php';

   ?>
```

Another code file:

```
   <?php
   $db_hostname = 'localhost';
   $db_database = 'cs12e2g_MyFirstDB'; //'Your database name'
   $db_username = 'cs12e2g_DBuser'; //'your username';
   $db_password = 'vtjppqs7'; //'Your password';
   $db_status = 'not initialised';
   $db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
   $db_status = "connected";
   if (!$db_server){
die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
$db_status = "not connected";
   }


    // Includes and variables always required

    require_once 'recaptcha/recaptchalib.php';
    require_once 'functions/cleanstring.php';
    $privatekey = "6Lem4-gSAAAAADsaa9KXlzSAhLs8Ztp83Lt-x1kn";
    $publickey = "6Lem4-gSAAAAAMHLAVbieIknMtUZo71ZKzzCkoFN";
    mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);

    $str_message = "";
    if (!$db_server){
        die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }else{

        if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
            $deleteq="DELETE FROM comments WHERE ID={$_GET['delete']} LIMIT 1";

            $deleter=mysqli_query($db_server, $deleteq);
            IF($deleter){
                echo"<p>That message was deleted!</p>";}}




        //Test whether form has been submitted 
        if(trim($_POST['submit']) == "Submit"){
            //Handle submission
            $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
            if (!$resp->is_valid) {
                // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
                $str_message = "The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it          
    again. 
                                (reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")";
            } else {

                // Your code here to handle a successful verification
               $comment = $_POST['comment'];
                if($comment != ""){
                    $query = "INSERT INTO comments (comment) VALUES ('$comment')";
                    mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die("Comment insert failed: " .        
    mysqli_error($db_server) );
                    $str_message = "Thanks for your comment!";
                }else{
                    $str_message = "Invalid form submission";
                }
            }
        }
        //Create page with or without submission 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM comments";
        $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
        if (!$result) die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server) );
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        $ID= $row['ID'];
            $str_result .=  "<p><em>Comment $j (" . $row['commDate'] . 
                    ")</em><br /> " .$row['comment'] . "</p>
                    <a href ='commentnow.php?delete=$ID
                    '>Delete</a><hr />"; 
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } 

     ?>




    <h1>What do you think?</h1>


   <p><h5>Did you find everything you wanted? Please comment below:<h5></p>

    <form action="commentnow.php" method="post">
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="comment"></textarea><br />
        <?php echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey); ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> 
    </form> 
    <span style="color:#FF0000;">
    <?php echo $str_message; ?></span>
    <hr /> 
    <h2>Comments:</h2>
    <?php echo $str_result; ?> 




    </div>

     <?php
require_once 'templates/close.php';


?>
```

I have a members.php page which corresponds to when the admin logs in (they are the only ones that can access this page) would the delete button code have to go in here? so they are the only ones that can use the function? If so where would it go, and how?

Comment: Despite the fact that you are using mysqli, your code is still subject to SQL injection as you are not using parameterized queries.

Comment: I've reverted the edits in this as a user replaced non-gendered pronouns and valid English spelling invalidly.

Answer (score 1):

Restrict the delete button to show only for the admin. Also this would mean that you somehow identify if the logged in user is an admin.

```
if ($is_admin) {
// Code to display button
}
```

Also in the backend check if the logged in user is admin

```
if ($is_admin) {
    // Code to delete comment
    delete_comment();
}
```

Comment: And also do the same for the code that actually does the delete in the backend too.

Comment: @developerwjk is right - it's way more important to restrict the code that actually does the delete than it is to hide the button that triggers said code.

Comment: thats great thank you! so where you have said to put if ($is_admin) {} should the $is_admin be $username (the username in my database

Comment: Add to your database table a new column `is_admin`. At the start of your script, query the database and return the value of `is_admin` (true/false or 1/0) assigning it to `$is_admin`. You can then implement raj's extract to check if the user is an admin or not.

Answer (score 0):

and you welcome to php.

You have that identify the users that enter in your application.

Using database or arrays or files or variables etc etc.

If permission is equal to admin or editor (For example) allow delete.

For example

```
if( $login == 'admin' ){
     // Allow action
}
```

My you understand?

(My English is bad, sorry)